# Why does using @Autowired not lead to a circular dependency, but autowiring the constructor does?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I've noticed a bit of a weird bug in an application I'm working on. While modifying a class, I moved a bunch of properties to be autowired in the constructor instead of using field injection, however, this caused me to get an error while starting up because of a circular dependency. Here's the breakdown of the dependency that caused an error:

- I am trying to use `ServiceA` inside of `TargetClass`.
- `ServiceA` has `ServiceB` injected through its constructor
- `ServiceB` has `ServiceC` injected through field injection
- `ServiceC` has `TargetClass` injected through field injection

I'm looking into ways of refactoring this, or trying to move some logic around into better places so I remove this circular dependency, however, I'm curious as to why two different methods of injecting `ServiceA` cause two different outcomes:

If I inject `ServiceA` through field injection, just using `@Autowired` on the field, my app starts just fine. However, if I switch `TargetClass` to use constructor injection, I will get an error about a circular dependency.

What is the difference in the way Spring handles the two types of injection that causes one to fail in this scenario, and the other to work?

Comment: By using @Autowired field injection, your dependencies are loaded when they are needed and not when your context is loaded. With constructor injection, spring cannot decide which service to create first. Check this: https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring

Comment: I think I'm understanding how this could happen. Let me know if this is your thinking as well: When I create it not using constructor injection, the first time it is needed, it doesn't require `ServiceA`, so it creates `TargetClass` without `ServiceA`. Later on, when `ServiceA` is needed, it's then created and we use the existing `TargetClass` that was created. When we do constructor injection, that's when this chain gets tripped because it has to create them all at once now, instead of waiting until there's a need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field injection works like

```
ServiceA serviceA = new ServiceA();
ServiceB serviceB = new ServiceB();
serviceA.serviceB = serviceB;
serviceB.serviceA = serviceA;
```

Constructor injection fails because

```
ServiceA serviceA = new ServiceA(????); // Cannot inject serviceB because to create serviceB I need serviceA which is being constructed
```

Though, there is way to have circular deps even with constructor.

```
class ServiceA {
  javax.inject.Provider<ServiceB> serviceBProvider;

  @Autowired ServiceA(javax.inject.Provider<ServiceB> serviceBProvider) {
     this.serviceBProvider = serviceBProvider;
  }

   void later() {
     this.serviceBProvider.get().methodOfServiceB();
   }

   void methodOfServiceA() {}
}

class ServiceB {
  javax.inject.Provider<ServiceA> serviceAProvider;

  @Autowired ServiceB(javax.inject.Provider<ServiceA> serviceAProvider) {
     this.serviceAProvider = serviceAProvider;
  }

   void later() {
     this.serviceAProvider.get().methodOfServiceA();
   }

   void methodOfServiceB() {}
}
```

It works because Spring does smth like that

```
Provider<ServiceA> serviceAProvider = new Provider<>();
Provider<ServiceB> serviceBProvider = new Provider<>();
ServiceA serviceA = new ServiceA(serviceBProvider);
ServiceB serviceB = new ServiceB(serviceAProvider);
serviceAProvider.set(serviceA);
serviceBProvider.set(serviceB);
```